# Web api service authentication for website as well as devices

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-web-api, owin

I am creating a web api data service. I want to use the service in a asp.net web site as well as apps for devices (iOS, Windows Phone, Android).

Which Authentication mechanism should I use ? I read around and found that the Bearer token with encryption is a good way.

I cannot understand how a website would propagate the identity to a web api service ? (because usually the mvc based web site has its on authentication built in!)

I know that I can some how delegate the authentication to a OWIN based module... I am not sure sure of the entire picture that all these technologies fit in.

Can anyone please explain me with a complete picture, how to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity propagation is simple, the device application either uses the login page automation or presents its own login interface to acquire the token and then uses the token in consecutive requests.

My recommendation would be to built your authentication around OAuth2 flows. There are three out of four flows you can find interesting.

The authorization code flow is for passive clients (other web applications). Your authentication server returns a one-time code that the application (resource server) uses to exchange it for a bearer token.

The token flow is for active clients that can access the login ui at the authentication server, for example javascript clients.

The resource owner flow allows mobile applications exchange username/password for a token which is a chance for hosting a custom login ui.

http://aaronparecki.com/articles/2012/07/29/1/oauth2-simplified

In practice, all these possible flows give clients a lot of flexibility regarding the integration. Because of the open nature of the protocol, clients built in any technology stack wold be able to use your authentication services.

If you follow this route and use the DotnetOpenAuth then yes, tokens carry encrypted information on user sessions so that there is no need for a persistent token repository.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I will read the article and look at the DotnetOpenAuth as well.